# What could cause an IQ diagram to shapeshift randomly?

Tags: software-defined-radio, satellites

I'm trying to interface a DVB-S2 transmitter to a DVB-S2 demodulator - for now with a direct cable+attenuator link. Both are set up exactly with the same parameters (same carrier frequency [2150MHz], same symbol rate [5Mbps], same modulation code [QPSK 1/2], same FEC frame size [Normal], same pilot tones [ON]...), but for a reason I cannot explain the IQ diagram shapeshifts between very distinct but very different patterns - none of which are QPSK.

[image]

Power spectrum:

[image]

Note that I also had this symptom using a dipole antenna on each port, instead of using a cable + series attenuators.

I have a similar RF power level to what I had when I looped the demodulator back onto itself, and that worked normally. So it looks like there is something wrong with the transmitter, but what sort of issue could cause these symptoms?

I'd rather not say the transmitter's P/N because I do not want to discredit the manufacturer if it turns out there is an issue with it, but the demodulator is a Teledyne QFlex400 (since I know it works, I have no issue with saying).

Comment: How are the transmitter and receiver physically synchronised? Does your soft receiver have a frequency recovery loop?

Comment: Yes, definitely a synchronization issue. This looks like signals moving in and out of phase with each other.

Comment: Thanks, I had a hunch there was something drifting out of phase but did not know what and how - because I looked everywhere and could not find anything about sync. On the demodulator I can only set the center frequency (they're set to the same) and the clock input on the demodulator is set to "satellite" but the only other options are through external interfaces and I fail to see how I could synchronise them in this way (by definition they're not in the same location).

Comment: This isn't a configuration option: symbol synchronization is a fundamental part of a digital receiver. The receiver needs to sample the signal at the right point to reconstruct the symbols that the transmitter is sending. To do that it needs to construct an estimate of the timing error between transmitter and receiver, and then reinterpolate the signal based on that. Your output looks like the symbol synchronization is failing; you can occasionally see something that looks like a QPSK constellation but it doesn't lock. It doesn't help much to diagnose the issue though, unfortunately.

Comment: You said the transmitter and receiver are configured for a symbol rate of 5Mbps - that's a little suspicious. Symbol rate is not measured in "bits per second"; it's "baud" or "symbols per second". QPSK encodes two bits per symbol. Is it possible the transmitter is sending 5M symbols per second, whereas the receiver is expecting 5M bits per second, or vice versa?

Comment: I wish I had - it was just a silly spelling error, I meant MSym/s. I did notice though that the demodulator, which I can loop back ok on itself, did not have the spectral regrowth we see here. Maybe the transmitter has been damaged and saturates?

Comment: Someone I know who works in RF says the spectral regrowth is due to power amplifiers being used and that it's normal. Back to square 1...